# Hunspell: Any solid example?

Tags: c++, wxwidgets, hunspell

I have downloaded and compiled hunspell fine. Now I want to make a test app on wxWidgets and I started looking for example or tutorial. So far I have found none. I can find "example" executable but no code (May be hidden somewhere haven't found?). In whole internet for three days I have found nothing. The best I have found [is this](http://blog.connor.hu/2009/11/21/hunspell-c-api/) which is in language I cannot understand.

I will appreciate any simple example, pointer to tutorial or anything of value for that matter.
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case anyone still needs a solid example, at least on ubuntu the package `libhunspell-dev` provides one in `/usr/share/doc/libhunspell-dev/examples/example.cxx`.

This file can also be found online, for example here: https://www.apt-browse.org/browse/ubuntu/precise/main/i386/libmythes-dev/2:1.2.2-1/file/usr/share/doc/libmythes-dev/examples/example.cxx

Based on this, I created a very small example for C++:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <hunspell/hunspell.hxx>

int main()
{
    Hunspell spell ("/usr/share/hunspell/en_US.aff", "/usr/share/hunspell/en_US.dic");

    std::cout << "Please enter one word:" << std::endl;
    std::string word;
    std::cin >> word;

    if (spell.spell(word.c_str()) == 0) {
            std::cout << "Spelling Error!";
    } else { 
            std::cout << "Correct Spelling!";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked this site?

http://sourceforge.net/projects/hunspell/files%2FHunspell%2FDocumentation/

It does not provide code by itself, but you can download thorough information from there.
The web page for **HunSpell** says that it is based on **MySpell**, maybe any source code out there for **MySpell** is compatible with **HunSpell**.